# Converting a file to string and back, Python Imaging Library

Tags: python, image

Im trying to convert a 25x25 px, 24bit PNG -file to a string and back with PIL.

```
from PIL import Image
a = Image.open("D:\\tmp\\img.png")
im = Image.fromstring("RGB", (25, 25), a.tostring('raw', "RGB"), 'raw', "RGB", 0, 1)
file = open("D:\\tmp\\img2.png", "w")
im.save(file)
```

There's something wrong with the output. I cannot open it with image viewing software. I tried different color modes without luck. What's the problem?

EDIT: added arguments to a.tostring() as suggested by Berserker, problem still exists

Here's the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sLzz.png I also tried with another one, no luck.

Comment: Please keep in mind `.fromstring()` is deprecated as referring to the [docs](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromstring).

Comment: Does it need to be accomplished with PIL?

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass your arguments to tostring.

I think it should be:

```
im = Image.fromstring("RGB", (25, 25), a.tostring('raw', "RGB"), 0, 1)
```